# Can I use the latest version of the appcompat library with a project that is targeting sdk 21

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I dont know much about this appcompat library so apologies if this isnt the smartest question.

I have a project that i was having a problem with. Turns out i had the targetSdkVersion set to 23 and it was causing me a problem since i wanted to use 21. So I changed it to 21.

In my build.gradle I have compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.

And this causes the following problems when i try to build:

> C:\Users\Conor\Documents\Programming\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\RouteTracker\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
>
> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Conor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit

So I tried to use appcompat of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.0 (as it was the only one i could definitively find), but it didnt work either. Says it couldnt find it and tells me to use the latest version, which is 23.1.1.

So should I be using 23.1.1? If so, any ideas what these errors are about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

It happens because you are using the support libraries **v23** which require to compile **with API 23.**

Change in your `build.gradle` this line:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

You can use another version of the support library but:

- pay attention to have another dependencies which use a latest version
- **the 21.1.0 doesn't exist**
- use the right api to compile

Here the full list:

```
  //it requires compileSdkVersion 23
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 22
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 21
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```

Comment: Cheers. Can you tell me where you got them from, I went looking last night and couldnt find them.

Comment: @discodowney All you need is to update your sdk manager. Updating the support library repository you have all these versions in your machine. Just add the right dependency in your build.gradle file.

Comment: Yeah I knew that, but i was just curious about the actual versions. The 22.0.0, 22.1.0. The list of actual versions. I realize its not that important but i was just curious

Comment: I am not sure about your question. Here the official full list: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Mark the answer if it resolves your issue. it can help other users.

Comment: I need **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.x.x**, please fill the 'x' in before code.

Answer (score 0):

No. AppCompat latest update remove some old dependencies. This is only available with v23. So, You have to update your code with targetSdkVersion 23.(marshmallow).

Comment: As explained in [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd) you can compile with an older SDK than you target

Answer (score 0):

You have got your solution but the answer to your questions 'Can I use the latest version of the appcompat library with a project that is targeting sdk 21' is as follows. Project lib should be compatible with 'compileSdkVersion' & not necessarily with targetSdkVersion. Ideally your compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion would be same but if your requirement is to target lower targetSdkVersion then you can keep it lower than compileSdkVersion.